# 'fetch' is not defined.eslint(no-undef) in react-native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I use fetch in react native and have a message : 'fetch' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)

my code:

```
getData() {
fetch('https://tutorialzine.com/misc/files/example.json', {})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

}

how can I fix it? and console.log not show data

Answer (score 25):

Set the environment for a browser inside the .eslintrc file:

```
env:
  browser: true
```

Answer (score 10):

`fetch` is a global method from browser environment. To silent eslint warning, you can put this in your eslint config file.

```
"globals": {
  "fetch": false
}
```

Here is a reference for this answer from [eslint issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4015#issuecomment-301920490).